# SQL code does not work

Tags: sql

How can i write a code that i want to choose name and adress of a customer which customer_id is bigger than him. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select c.name,a.adress,a.postcode_id from customer c left join Adress a on c.customer_id=a.customer_id where c.customer_id>11
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cs.name,ad.adress 
FROM Customer cs, Adress ad 
WHERE cs.customer_id=ad.customer_id
AND cs.customer_id>11;
```